# Angular convert JSON to model and store in array

Tags: angular

I seem to have a problem mapping the returned JSON to my object array.
Here is the JSON that I want to be transformed to an object, and put in an array.

```
{ danceability: 0.653,
  energy: 0.59,
  key: 5,
  loudness: -9.649,
  mode: 1,
  speechiness: 0.104,
  acousticness: 0.000942,
  instrumentalness: 0.378,
  liveness: 0.2,
  valence: 0.625,
  tempo: 168.054,
  type: 'audio_features',
  id: '7bsPIUEEOuL5WlOPcYUrYx',
  uri: 'spotify:track:7bsPIUEEOuL5WlOPcYUrYx',
  track_href: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7bsPIUEEOuL5WlOPcYUrYx',
  analysis_url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/7bsPIUEEOuL5WlOPcYUrYx',
  duration_ms: 293307,
  time_signature: 4 }
```

This is my interface for the object. It's called SpotifyAudioFeatures

```
export interface SpotifyAudioFeatures {
  danceability: number;
  energy: number;
  key: number;
  loudness: number;
  mode: number;
  speechiness: number;
  acousticness: number;
  instrumentalness: number;
  liveness: number;
  valence: number;
  tempo: number;
  type: string;
  id: string;
  uri: string;
  track_href: string;
  analysis_url: string;
  duration_ms: number;
  time_signature: number;
  }
```

My Service class and method is:

```
getAudioFeatures(tracks): Observable<SpotifyAudioFeatures[]>{
    return this.httpClient.post<SpotifyAudioFeatures[]>('http://localhost:3000/getAudioFeatures', 
    {
      'tracks' :tracks
    }
    ).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

And my method on my component.ts is:

```
  spotifyAudioFeaturesArray : SpotifyAudioFeatures[];


    getAudioFeatures(track){
        this.spotifyService.getAudioFeatures(track).subscribe(
          (data) => {
            console.log(data);  //I can see the JSON printed here
            this.spotifyAudioFeaturesArray = data;           
          },
          (err) => console.log(err)
        );
          console.log(this.spotifyAudioFeatures)  //This shows up as undefined   
      }
```

I'm not sure why the array 'spotifyAudioFeaturesArray' is returning blank? I have looked at a few tutorials, and for most of them the array is populated, but not on mine. Not sure what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The **second `console.log`** is actually **executing first** because of the **asynchronous nature** of observables and the `.subscribe` function
- `this.spotifyAudioFeaturesArray = data;` is executing **after the POST request** (which is after the second `console.log`
- Since you didn't initialize it `spotifyAudioFeaturesArray : SpotifyAudioFeatures[];` it doesn't hold any value yet. Thus printing the `undefined`

Comment: That seems work! But when I do  a
console.log("acousticness is: "+this.spotifyAudioFeaturesArray[0].acousticness),
Then it gives me an error "Cannot read property 'acousticness' of undefined".
Does this mean the mapping is still not there?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're saying. And that's not related to the first question by the way, maybe post it in another question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `console.log(this.spotifyAudioFeatures)` is the only place you're checking it, this might be a result of async nature of `spotifyService.getAudioFeatures()` function.

Due to the asynchronous nature of Observables, JS calls `this.spotifyService.getAudioFeatures()` but doesn't wait for the result, and goes to `console.log(this.spotifyAudioFeatures)`.

Since `getAudioFeatures()` didn't finish executing yet, `this.spotifyAudioFeatures` is still undefined.

To fix it, try putting that console.log right after `this.spotifyAudioFeaturesArray = data;`

Like this:

```
getAudioFeatures(track){
    this.spotifyService.getAudioFeatures(track).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.spotifyAudioFeaturesArray = data;
        console.log(this.spotifyAudioFeatures);       // here   
      },
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to print the json, but when I do a .length on the array or do array[0], it shows up as undefined again

Comment: @Abhinav Could you tell me where in the code you are trying to access the length and the first element?

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the content of `spotifyAudioFeaturesArray` before it is actually populated, because `getAudioFeatures` is an async request. Your code works fine, your `console.log` statement is just in the wrong place.

Move your `console.log` statement into your `subscribe` block and it should log the content properly.

```
getAudioFeatures(track) {
  this.spotifyService.getAudioFeatures(track).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.spotifyAudioFeaturesArray = data;
      console.log(this.spotifyAudioFeatures);           
    },
    (err) => console.log(err)
  );
}
```